# Slick TextureLoader.getTexture cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, slick2d

I think it is just the wrong implementation of the Libary, but i don' know how to resolve it.

[funktion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Al3lJ.png)

It seems like the class Texture (org.newdawn.slick.opengl.Texture) doesn't work or...

Imports work...

import org.newdawn.slick.opengl.Texture;
import org.newdawn.slick.opengl.TextureLoader;

I realy don't know, whats going on.

```
package Main.graphics;

import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL15.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL30.*;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.nio.IntBuffer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.lwjgl.BufferUtils;
import org.newdawn.slick.opengl.Texture;
import org.newdawn.slick.opengl.TextureLoader;

import Main.models.Model;

public class ModelLoader {

    // nach Thin Matrix

    private List<Integer> vaos = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private List<Integer> vbos = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private List<Integer> textures = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public Model loadToVAO(float[] positions, int[] indices) {
        int vaoID = createVAO();
        bindIndicesBuffer(indices);
        storeDataInAttribList(0, positions);
        unbindVAO();
        return new Model(vaoID, indices.length);
    }

    public void destroyAll() {
        for (int vao : vaos) {
            glDeleteVertexArrays(vao);
        }
        for (int vbo : vbos) {
            glDeleteBuffers(vbo);
        }
        for (int texture : textures) {
            glDeleteTextures(texture);
        }
    }

    public int loadTexture(String textureReference) {
        Texture texture = null; // <--- light blue (seen as variable name?)
        try {
            texture = new TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG", new FileInputStream("res/" + textureReference + ".png"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { // ^ TextureLoader.getTexture cannot be resolved to a type
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        int textureID = texture.getTextureID();
        textures.add(textureID);
        return textureID;
    }

    private int createVAO() {
        int vaoID = glGenVertexArrays();
        vaos.add(vaoID);
        glBindVertexArray(vaoID);
        return vaoID;
    }

    private void unbindVAO() {
        glBindVertexArray(0);
    }

    private void bindIndicesBuffer(int[] indices) {
        int vboID = glGenBuffers();
        vbos.add(vboID);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID);
        IntBuffer buffer = storeDataInIntBuffer(indices);
        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    }

    private void storeDataInAttribList(int attribNumber, float[] data) {
        int vboID = glGenBuffers();
        vbos.add(vboID);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID);
        FloatBuffer buffer = storeDataInFloatBuffer(data);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glVertexAttribPointer(attribNumber, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    }

    private IntBuffer storeDataInIntBuffer(int[] data) {
        IntBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(data.length);
        buffer.put(data);
        buffer.flip();
        return buffer;
    }

    private FloatBuffer storeDataInFloatBuffer(float[] data) {
        FloatBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(data.length);
        buffer.put(data);
        buffer.flip();
        return buffer;
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please copy the source code into your question; we cannot easily test it otherwise. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for tips on how to ask a gread question.

Comment: i added the class